# Datepicker jquery over all frames

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to use Date picker in a frame (main page is composed of 2 frames) and when I click in the textbox the calendar appers in the same frame, drops down with scroll so that it is invisibile (you need to scroll to see it). I want to make it to drop over all the frames. The code I use is the following:

```
 $(function() {

        $('#datepicker').datepicker({minDate: '0', maxDate: '+1Y+6M', onSelect: function(dateStr) {
            var min = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); // Get selected date
            $('#datepicker2').datepicker('option', 'minDate', min || '0'); // Set other min, default to today
        }});
        $('#datepicker2').datepicker({minDate: '0', maxDate: '+1Y+6M', onSelect: function(dateStr) {
            var max = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); // Get selected date
            $('#datepicker').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', max || '+1Y+6M'); // Set other max, default to +18 months
        }});
    });
```

All comments will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        //datetimepicker
        $(function () {
            $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                dateFormat: 'dd M yy',
                showAnim: 'slideDown'
            });
        });
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtentrydate" CssClass="datepicker" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
```

this code for desired textbox calender

Comment: Thank you for response, but it still doesn't work.. Maybe I do smth wrong? Should I just add this script?

Comment: where you using textbox use this cssclass="datepicker" it is working or check you jquery version download new version and try it

Comment: I implement calendar like this   <input type="text" id="datepicker"/>  and in doesnt work.. i'll be appreciated if you can advise me this new version, beacause all i've tried unfortunally dont work